# Edit 1: Displaying the sign in Name from Azure AD

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure

Basically I want to display various fields of a user from azure AD.
I am able to display all the fields except the signInName.
The signin property is of the type:
IList IUser.SignInNames {get;} that is why my logic is not working as I am using a single console.writeline().

Below is my code:

```
private static async Task PeoplePickerExample(IActiveDirectoryClient client, string searchString)
        {

            List<IUser> usersList = null;
            IPagedCollection<IUser> searchResults = null;
            try
            {
                IUserCollection userCollection = client.Users;
                searchResults = await userCollection.Where(user =>
                    user.UserPrincipalName.StartsWith(searchString) ||
                    user.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchString) ||
                    user.GivenName.StartsWith(searchString) ||
                    user.Surname.StartsWith(searchString)).Take(10).ExecuteAsync();
                usersList = searchResults.CurrentPage.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Program.WriteError("\nError getting User {0}", Program.ExtractErrorMessage(e));
            }

            if (usersList != null && usersList.Count > 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    int index = 1;
                    usersList = searchResults.CurrentPage.ToList();

                    foreach (IUser user in usersList)
                    {
                        IUserFetcher userFetcher = user as IUserFetcher;
                        IDirectoryObject manager = await userFetcher.Manager.ExecuteAsync();
                        IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> reports = await userFetcher.DirectReports.ExecuteAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine("Sign in name:{0}", user.SignInNames);
                        Console.WriteLine("Manager:" + ((IUser)(manager)).DisplayName);
                        Console.WriteLine("Country:{0}", user.Country);
                        Console.WriteLine("Mail Nickname:{0}", user.MailNickname);
                        index++;
                    }
                    searchResults = await searchResults.GetNextPageAsync();
                } while (searchResults != null);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User not found");
            }

        }
```

Please check the line where I use this:
 Console.WriteLine("Sign in name:{0}", user.SignInNames);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.NonEntityTypeCollectionImpl`1[Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.SignInName]

If there is no SignInNames, the console application will show above message. The property "SignInNames" contains the collection of sign-in names used by a local account user to sign in to an Azure Active Directory B2C tenant. We could find this information at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-versioning). If you does not use Azure AD B2C tenant, or there is no local account user to sign in. It will show you with above info.

Comment: so how do i fetch the signinname for corpnet or microsoft users? which property shall i use?

Comment: What does your sign in name mean? We can use UserPrincipalName to show signin email, or use Display Name/First Name &Last Name to show its login name. Do you use B2C tenant?

Comment: Hello Jambor,
thanks for the revert. yes I use a B2C tenant. I think the problem with the above code is the way I display the signinName. I think the issue is with the type. it is IList<signinname> Iuser signinnames. I think we need to display it differently on the console???